# Unable to download putty in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, putty

I am not able to download putty in ubuntu. it gives below error

```
download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 installed oracle-java8-installer package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am using below command to install putty in command prompt.

```
sudo apt install putty
```

It says that i don't have jdk installed. I already tried to install jdk 8 mentioned in below link:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ELB201/Installing+Java+Development+Kit+%28JDK%29+on+Linux
but it is not allowing me to download jdk.
I have jdk-8u72-linux-x64.tar.gz file downloaded previously and I have unzipped it. still no success. same error came oracle jdk not installed.

Comment: IIRC PuTTY doesn't require Java, which means the problem stems from an earlier incomplete or failed installation of Java.

Comment: have you tried `yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk`?

Comment: yum, in a debian-based distribution like ubuntu? I thought this was only meant for redhat-based ones...

Comment: This is also off-topic here, and more suitable to be asked either on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour/), the [Unix & Linux SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to download putty on Ubuntu, because you can use the default terminal of Ubuntu. You just need to connect to a server like:

```
ssh user_name@server_address
```

and hit the enter button. Then enter the server password when it asks for the password.

Comment: Maybe he's used to the UI interface, or wants to use some of the other capabilities that putty gives... I mean, I agree with you to some extent but I don't think this helps solve his problem at all